# Applying results of case when statement to distinct serial numbers

Tags: r

I have survey data for households with all individuals in a household identifiable by a unique serial number regardless of demographic information. I am looking to apply the results from a mutate, case_when statement in R to unique serial numbers (everyone in the household).

example:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(result = case_when(salary >= 2000 ~ "Qualify", TRUE ~ "Not Qualified"))
```

But I want it to apply to distinct serial numbers regardless of salary amount so long as one serial number has salary greater than or equal to 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by the serial number and then using `any()` to see if there are any values within that group that qualify should get you there:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(serial_number) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(any(salary >= 2000) ~ "Qualify", TRUE ~ "Not Qualified"))
```